# How to change or modify the default Home sreen while start up of Android

Tags: android

I have a requirement to change the default Home screen at start up of Android.
like whenever i start the emulator then my own customize screen or default page should come instead of Android default screen.

Thanks in Advence

Reagrds
Bijay...

Comment: The very very first thing to do is searching in Google. I could have posted a direct link to a popular sample project in the answer, but what you are looking for can be found in the first page of a SINGLE Google search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own Home Screen and make it as default. There are several available in the Android Market. Have a look at CATEGORY_HOME at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

I Googled "android home activity" and this came up as the 4th result:

http://adamac.blogspot.com/2007/12/replacing-android-home-screen.html

tl;dr:  Use `<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />` and the system will prompt the user which Home activity the user would prefer when starting the Home activity.  They can check the 'use by default' button and it'll stop prompting.